# Nested Explosion in PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to explode a very nested dataframe, which has nesting till 3-4 levels, and wanted to know how to explode in a optimized and precise manner!

Schema of the Nested DataFrame:

```
root
 |-- uuid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- start_date: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- array1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- level: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- array2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- array3: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- count: long (nullable = true)
```

After explosion the output should look like:

```
uuid, start_date, array1.level, array1.array2.name, array1.array2.array3.count
```

I've somehow achieved this with a sequential explode each and every array one-byone, but I think that is a very inefficient process and looking for other ideas!

Comment: Are you using azure databricks

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula No, actually. Just a simple pyspark job on local.